# Drupal 7 "Active forum topics" modify block/view

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-7, block, forum

On the main page of my drupal 7 website I have a a block called "active forum topics. At the moment only the topic title is shown in the preview:

[image]

Is there a way to modify this block? I want to add more content to this block like author of the topic, related forum, date/time, maybe number of posts.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might consider asking this on Stack Overflow's Drupal Answers forum rather than here.. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Well I actually have an answer for this, after looking to do it myself, I found the "view" for the "Active Forum Topics" page (the forum tab page that generates active forum topics).  From that view I added a block, which now allows you to create a block from that existing view - with whatever items you want in there.

Assuming you are using advanced forum - this view is at:  admin/structure/views/view/advanced_forum_active_topics

Where is says "displays" click the (+add) button and choose block.  From there it is pretty straight forward if you know how to use views.